# image from mysql to html by php-code needed

Tags: php, mysql, image

i want to retrieve image stored in mysql as path using php and display in a table together with other text data in other columns of the table.i tried different codes but in vain. can anybody help me by providing code. thanks

Comment: Your question is quite vague. Perhaps showing your database structure and any existing code might help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like:

```
<?

    $query = "SELECT ImageURL from WhateverTable";

    $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

    $Image = mysql_fetch_row($result);

    echo "<img src='$Image[0]' alt='This is an image'>";

?>
```

Then just put it in the table you like.